# Why are the moderators here so poor in their knowledge of Bible events

Tags: discussion

Take a look at Caleb's response that this event did not happen, and then right below theres a reply with a scripture.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/if-abraham-really-believed-in-god-why-did-he-lie-and-let-pharaoh-take-sarah-why

Comment: Personally, I think our moderators are brilliant!  (and incredibly humble, [like Moses](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2012:3&version=NIV))

Comment: Because they think they're more holy than everyone else.

Comment: Why does older (first) question got closed and merged with another question as being exact same duplicate??? Appart, that these questions are completely different from one another...

Answer (score 17):

1. Being a moderator here does not mean that you have an extensive Bible knowledge.  It means you have been selected by the community (or in early Beta, by the SE staff) as someone who is responsible, level-headed, and fair, when dealing with the community.  There is likely to be an overlap between someone who is selected, and willing to be a mod on this site, and someone who has a certain level of Bible knowledge, but there's no guarantee.
2. It sounds like your real question is "Why was this question closed?"  I suggest asking that question, if that's what you really mean.

Answer (score 10):

My understanding is that Caleb has less of an issue with the event described than the way it was depicted. It did not happen as depicted in the question and the user was suspended so it was not worth editing the question to save it. Thus it was closed instead of edited in order to make the question constructive an answerable.

Comment: This is correct. My wording could have been better. I'm well aware an event happened involving Sarah and Pharaoh, but since it didn't happen the way the OP depicted it...